# What's different with Spring Kafka MessageListenerContainer start/Resume / stop/ Pause # spring-kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

```
        for (MessageListenerContainer e : containers) {
            if (!e.isContainerPaused()) {
                e.pause();
                e.stop();
            } else {
                e.resume();
                e.start();
            }
        }
```

in my springboot-kafka project I want to control these container, but I don't know what's the different on pause / stop  or  resume / start.
thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pause-resume

The pause/resume is, essentially, a `KafkaConsumer` feature to prevent rebalance when we cannot keep up for `poll.interval`. See more in its docs: https://medium.com/@vaibhav.vb24/kafka-confluent-pause-and-resume-consumer-cda7305944bf.

The start/stop is a Spring's lifecycle management feature. You subscribe to the topic and start consuming from it when the `start()` is called. You stop consuming and unsubscribe from the topic when `stop()` is called. This way a rebalance happens for the consumer group. See more info in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#connecting

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor

Comment: thanks for your answer, i understand. in my project, I will use pause/resume. because if use start/stop ,grafana or other monitoring software may bring unnecessary alarm. On the other hand, I don't need to rebalance. thank you